# Why does my RT (Real-Time) Linux freeze when I create a RT process with infinite loop?

Tags: c, linux, real-time

I build my RT Linux kernel with RT-Preempt Patch(kernel is build under FULL PREEMPT option) on Ubuntu 20.04, the kernel version is 5.9.1, but the RT system got freezes when I run my test process. The test process just forks a RT child process with infinite loop, I really don't know what happens. The source code acts as follows:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <sys/ptrace.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sched.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <pthread.h>

void pinCPU(unsigned coreNo) {
    cpu_set_t mask;
    CPU_ZERO(&mask);
    CPU_SET(coreNo, &mask);
    assert(0 == sched_setaffinity(0, sizeof(cpu_set_t), &mask));
}

void setFIFO() {
    pid_t pid = getpid();
    struct sched_param param;
    param.sched_priority = sched_get_priority_max(SCHED_FIFO)-10;
    assert(0 <= sched_setscheduler(pid, SCHED_FIFO, &param));
}

int main() {
    pid_t pid = fork();
    if (pid == 0) {
        // child process
        pinCPU(1);
        setFIFO();
        assert(-1 != ptrace(PTRACE_TRACEME, 0, 0, 0));
        while(1);
    } else if (pid > 0) {
        int count = 0, status;
        printf("child:%d count: %d\n", pid, count);
        while(++count <= 3) {
            status = -1;
            waitpid(-1, &status, 0);
            printf("child:%d count: %d\n", pid, count);
            assert(-1 != ptrace(PTRACE_CONT, pid, 0, 0));
        }
        kill(pid, SIGKILL);
        puts("kill child and exit!");
    }
}
```

When I change the body of infinite loop as follows, the CPU utilization lowered from 99% to 40%, the RT Linux didn't freeze anymore. So does the RT process with high CPU utilization crash the RT kernel? But I cannot tell any reasonable explanation with it.

```
unsigned long long t;
while(1) {
    t = 1 << 63;
    while(--t);
    usleep(100);
}
```

Note: Both test processes I've mentioned above work well on Ubuntu 20.04 without RT-Preempt patched kernel.

Comment: Please note that any `assert()` that has a side-effect (like `assert(0 <= sched_setscheduler(pid, SCHED_FIFO, &param));`) is a programming error as the `asserts` may be optimized away. In general describe in greater detail what the intention of your program is.

Answer (score 2):

From `man 7 sched`:

```text
Limiting the CPU usage of real-time and deadline processes
       A nonblocking infinite loop in a thread scheduled under the SCHED_FIFO,
       SCHED_RR, or SCHED_DEADLINE policy  can  potentially  block  all  other
       threads  from  accessing  the  CPU forever.  Prior to Linux 2.6.25, the
       only way of preventing a runaway real-time process  from  freezing  the
       system  was  to  run  (at the console) a shell scheduled under a higher
       static priority than the tested application.  This allows an  emergency
       kill of tested real-time applications that do not block or terminate as
       expected.

       Since Linux 2.6.25, there are other techniques for dealing with runaway
       real-time  and  deadline  processes.   One  of  these  is  to  use  the
       RLIMIT_RTTIME resource limit to set a ceiling on the CPU  time  that  a
       real-time process may consume.  See getrlimit(2) for details.
...
```

So the answer to

> So does the RT process with high CPU utilization crash the RT kernel?

is "**No**"; the effect observed is being described above.
If the kernel would crash, you'd either see some message or experience a reboot.
(I'm considering "the kernel freezes" and "the kernel crashes" to be two different things, and I don't even believe the "kernel freezes" for the reasons given above.)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll try again anyway. But I really want to know the reason why a rt process with infinite loop can potentially block all  other threads. In fact, this problem first appears as I run SPEC benchmarks under the SCHED_FIFO on my rt linux to measure performance metrics, so an emergency kill for the tested real-time application isn't what I want.

Comment: Please read the complete manual page cited: A SCHED_FIFO thread consuming all CPU will *not* block all other threads, but it will get CPU before any  threads with a lower priority. A real-time thread that needlessly consumes all CPU is simply a programming error.